# Print() and NSLog output on IOS device

Tags: ios, swift

Where can I find the output from my `print()` and `NSLog` statements when the app is running on my iOS device?

I can't find it in the console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Xcode 9

Go to Xcode --> Window --> Devices

Select the device and tap in *open console* button. You can see how looks the button in the image attached below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaZYN.png)

Answer (score 5):

On Xcode 7.2

Go to Xcode --> **Window** --> **Devices**.

Select the **device**, click in the left botton of the white screen in the button points up.

[image]

You can also see crash log of your apps clicking in the **Device Logs** at the same screen.

Answer (score 2):

As some have already mentioned, if you have your device connected using a cable, you should get the logs directly into XCode console.

Also, if you are running the app without having it connected, you can later connect the device to your computer and open XCode. From the Device organizer you can get the past logs.

I recommend you also to take a look at [Bugfender](http://bugfender.com), it's a product we have built to solve this problem when we don't have access to our customers devices. With Bugfender you can get the logs from any devices even if you don't have direct access to it.

It's easy to integrate and you can choose which devices you want to get the logs from. Our service works offline and online, we have spent a lot of time to make it reliable and easy to use.

Comment: Hi!. I want to use Bugfender and need to get device logs if needed.
I have one question: Can I collect all NSLogs stored in file in application and if I need, user can press button and application can upload the file with these logs to the Bugfender?
I don't need to send logs always, only file(s) with logs when needed. Can I do it with Bugfender?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're connected to the device via cable, debugging with Xcode you should see it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

[1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html  <--- This is Apple's instructions for finding your NSLog output on the device without XCode or with the various XCode versions.